# Bash equivalent of PowerShell script embedded in R Script to run on Rshiny server

Tags: r, bash, curl

I am using the following script to query and fetch data utilizing the solr API and read the generated csv output as a csv file. I want to port this script to run in RShiny server. Any suggestions please?

```
url <- "curl 'https://[site.orgnaization.com/solr/someFolder/select?q=*:*&rows=1000&wt=csv' -L -u  username:password --location-trusted -b cookie-jar.txt > C:/Folder/Filename.csv"

fileConn <- file("C:/Folder/PowerShellFile.ps1")
writeLines(url, fileConn)
close(fileConn)
system2("PowerShell", args = c("-file", "C:\\Folder\\PowerShellFile.ps1"))

DataFromSolr <- data.frame(read.csv("C:/Folder/Filename.csv",header = TRUE, sep = "," , fill = TRUE ,fileEncoding = "UTF-16LE"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed PowerShell from this site [https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/docs/installation/linux.md#ubuntu-1604] on the linux server and that solved the problem.